# python keyboard module buserror/segmentation fault

Tags: python, macos, keyboard

I am trying to use the keyboard module. I just wrote

```
import keyboard
```

and thats all in the file and it gives me this error

```
zsh: bus error
```

but sometimes it gives me this error

```
zsh: segmentation fault
```

I have no idea what is happening as I have used this module before and it has worked fine. If it matters I am on OSX
thanks!